# Return rows which have same data in three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[personas](
    [id_persona] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nombres] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [apellido_paterno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [apellido_materno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [fecha_nacimiento] [date] NOT NULL,
    [sexo] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [estado_civil] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [calle] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [colonia] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [codigo_postal] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [telefonos] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [celular] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
```

How do I make a query in SQL Server to return rows where `nombre`, `apellido_paterno` and `apellido_materno` are repeated? I mean two or more rows have the same data in these columns.

I suppose I'm looking something opposite to DISTINCT clause

Comment: one approach would be to minus distinct from the total set. but thats not efficient!

Comment: yep, but then how do I get which rows are the repeated?

Comment: Are you looking for records that have duplicate 'nombre', 'apellido_paterno' and 'apellido_materno' values?

Comment: This sounds like you're going to be deduping on name and maternal and paternal surname, which may not necessarily be the way to go. Depending on the size of your userbase. If you are deduping I'd definitely include other metrics.

Comment: @Ben i'm just looking for a quick solution since I've made some adjustments and by now you can't duplicate records, but in the past it was possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want...

```
SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno
  FROM dbo.personas
 GROUP BY nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to look at the actual rows, then use that as an inner query and join onto it. So, something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM personas pOuter INNER JOIN
    (SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno
      FROM dbo.personas
     GROUP BY nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) pInner
    ON pInner.nombre = pOuter.nombre 
   AND pInner.apellido_paterno = pOuter.apellido_paterno
   AND pInner.apellido_materno = pOuter.apellido_materno
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT id_personas, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (
   PARTITION BY nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno
   ORDER BY id_personas
  )
  FROM dbo.personas
)
SELECT <col list> 
FROM dbo.personas AS p
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM x 
  WHERE x.id_personas = p.id_personas 
  AND x.rn > 1
);
```

Comment: I have two doubts in your answer, what do <col list> and x.rn mean?

Comment: @Jorge <col list> is a placeholder for whatever columns you actually need on output. That may be all columns, but it is still better to list them than to use SELECT *. x.rn refers to the ROW_NUMBER() established in the CTE. Replace <col list> with * and try it.

Comment: Oh I see, very neat answer. I'm just wondering which of the answers has a better performance, I think I will try both once my database is more populated. Thanks for your time